# D3 force layout that moves branches in tree instead of nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a tree and additional links between the leafs. I want to apply force layout for those nodes, so that the branches are forced to move closer together. Not the separate nodes (the tree layout should be preserved).

So for image below I want branches that start in 7 and and 4 to change places, so that nodes 5 and 0 become closer. So far I acheaved moving only separate nodes together. See another image below.

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/1ahutwvp/35/) Could you please suggest the best way to change the places of branches using force layout?

[image]

[image]

I applied force layout only on some nodes:

```
// assign special type on creation/////////////////////////////////////
var ind1 = 0;
var ind2 = 5;
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  if (i ==  ind1 || i == ind2) {
    d.dataType = 'special';
  } else {
    d.dataType = 'none';
  }
}
)
// draw path between special nodes/////////////////////////////////////
var nodeS = nodes[ind1];
    var nodeT = nodes[ind2];
    var newLink = {source: nodeS, target: nodeT};
    specialLinks.push(newLink);
    nodesSelected.push(nodeS);
    nodesSelected.push(nodeT);

    linkSel = svg.selectAll('path.linkExtra').data(specialLinks);
    nodeSel = svg.selectAll('g.node').filter(function(d,i){
      return d3.select(this).attr('data-type') == 'special';
    })

    linkSel.enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', 'linkExtra')
        .attr('d', d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) {
          return [d.y, d.x];
        }));

// create force layout/////////////////////////////////////
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(0)
  .charge(20)
  .linkDistance(100)
  .linkStrength(1)
  .size([500, 500]);



 // main function to apply forces/////////////////////////////////////
     function inittForce() { 
    force
        .nodes(nodesSelected)
        .links(specialLinks)
         .start();


    force.on('tick', function(e) {

      linkSel.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      nodeSel.attr('cx', function(d, i) {return  d.x;})
          .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });

      svg.selectAll('*').remove();
      drawTree();
      drawPath();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a picture clarifying  how you would like to position the nodes? Maybe force layout is not the best option in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think force layout in conjunction with hierarchy layout is going to work here.

I would look to programmatically pre-pocess the data, so that the data sent to the hierarchical layout is ordered based on its connectivity. For your example I have swapped around a couple of the `treeData` array elements to get the effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ahutwvp/39/

Comment: thanks, yes, I also thought that this is a bad idea to use force layout for that after a while